# regarding scrolling inside UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a scroll view with some content. After loading the contents I am using the following code to move to the top of the scroll view

```
  [scrollViewCustom setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) animated:NO];
```

It works. With one exception :

I have a `UITextView`. If I add some text to it, then the scroll view never goes back to the top with this code. I have to manually scroll to the top.

I have even tried to put the same code after adding text to the `UITextView`.

Can anyone kindly help out ? Thanks.

NB:So, heres the solution :

Basically `UITextView` derives from `UIScrollView` and as such, whenever there is some text there, it tries to scroll to make the text visible. I have replaced `UITextView` to `UILabel` and it works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 [scrollViewCustom setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) animated:NO];
```

Use

```
[scroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0, 100,100) animated:NO];
```

Comment: what happened, please decribe

Comment: Its the same, With the given code, It doesnt scroll to the top, I have to manually do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
 scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 400);
 }

 - (void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView {  
CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y;  
CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; 
CGFloat availableHeight;

    availableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - 300; 

CGFloat z = viewCenterY - availableHeight / 2.0;  
if (z < 0) {  
    z = 0;  
 }  
 [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, z) animated:YES];  
}

-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
[self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:scroll];

}

 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementText:(NSString *)text
 {
if (range.length==0) {
    [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];  
        return NO;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just two steps:

```
// define the area that is initially visible
 scrollViewCustom.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 354, 500);

// then define how much a user can scroll it
[scrollViewCustom setContentSize:CGSizeMake(354, 960)];

In addition,clear the background color of scroll view to show the text. 
scrollViewCustom.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I can move it, BUT manually, not with the given code.